# ejs returning empty array but console.log returns an value

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a variable that returns fine in console.log() but when rendering it returns an empty array.

```
function loadFestival(festSlug) {
  return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
    Collection.findOne({
      slug: festSlug
    }).deepPopulate('events shows')

    .exec(function(err, model) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      if (!model) {
        return reject(new Error('Festival not found for slug: ' + festSlug));
      }

      var show_performances = [];

      model.shows.forEach(function(show) {
        var showID = show._id.toString();



        show_performances[showID] = []
        show_performances[showID]['performances'] = [];
        show_performances[showID]['ticketing'] = [];

        model.events.forEach(function(event) {
          if (show._id.toString() == event.show.toString()) {
            show_performances[showID]['performances'].push(moment(event.dateRange.start).format('YYYY MMM D'));
            show_performances[showID]['ticketing'][moment(event.dateRange.start).format('YYYY MMM D')] = event.ticketing_url;
          }
        });
      });
      resolve(show_performances);
    });
  });
}
```

From comments:

```
//Here is the code running 
loadFestival('slug').then(function(model) {
  console.log(model) //returns as should be 
  res.render('.//index.html', {
    layout: layout,
    model: JSON.stringify(model) // returns nothing 
  });
});
```

The above code returns as it should be in console.log(show_performances) but when rendering nothing returns. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your snippet of ejs where you are rendering this?

Comment: its just a html page with <%=show_performances %>

Comment: for some reason its skipping "show_performances[showID]"

Comment: Where are you using `console.log()` that it's working?

Comment: `loadFestival('slug').then(function(model){
console.log(model) //returns as should be

res.render('.//index.html',{
            layout: layout,
            model: JSON.stringify(model) // returns nothing 

        });
}`

Comment: added a full code - so should be clear now.

Comment: From the looks of it. You are calling `res.render` twice. First within `loadFestival`. Then again when you call the function `loadFestival` externally.

Comment: just removed the first render , that is just for showing up, but on the next loadFestival function returns the render.

Comment: Shouldn't <%=show_performances %> be <%=model.show_performances %> ? If that doesn't work, try <%=model %>, you might need to parse it as json first